# Converting string in list of list into float

Tags: python

i have a list of list with:

```
[['9.2','8.7'],['7.5','6.5']]
```

and i want to convert them into float values to get:

```
[[9.2,8.7],[7.5,6.5]]
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
L = [['9.2','8.7'],['7.5','6.5']]
for line in L:
    if line:
        line = [float(i) for i in line]
print(L)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't changing the original but creating a new list, so you are not seeing any side effects in `L`. You can just create  a new list with your code:

```
L = [['9.2','8.7'],['7.5','6.5']]
newL = []
for line in L:
    newL.append([float(i) for i in line])
print(newL)
```

Alternatively, use a list comprehension:

```
newL = [[float(n) for n in e] for e in L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested list comprehension to write:

```
new_L = [[float(item) for item in line] for line in L]
```